# select all data from a column where data selected in another one power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am starting on Power BI,
I need to do a measure in POWER BI when I select for example Esteban, I need to filter all sales made by Esteban included with all the other guys.

I have two tables

one

vendors with 1 Column
VendorName
Esteban
Horacio
Luis
Rosa
Nick

And another table with all the sales but some sales are done for multiple vendors. for example

sale 1  done by Esteban - Horacio - Luis -
sale 2  done by Esteban
sale 3  done by Esteban - Rosa
sale 4  done by Marcos - Esteban
sale 5  done by Nick
sale 6  done by Horacio - Luis
sale 7  done by Rosa - Nick

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please test this and let me know if It solves your problem: You can select any name from your vendor slicer.

```
Sales_By_VendorName =
VAR SalesRep =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( vendors[VendorName] )
VAR SummaryTable =
    FILTER ( Sales, CONTAINSSTRING ( Sales[VendorName], SalesRep ) )
RETURN
    SummaryTable
```

Comment: thanks Ozan! I just need to return SummaryTable, then 
Sales_By_VendorName =
VAR SalesRep =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( vendors[VendorName] )
VAR SummaryTable =
    FILTER ( Sales, CONTAINSSTRING ( Sales[VendorName], SalesRep ) )
RETURN
Return (SummaryTable)

Comment: yes, precisely. 

Comment: Hi Marcos, Please accept the answer if It solved your problem.